# JS Syntax Error: DOCTYPE html

Tags: javascript, ajax, forms, jquery

I have a form being submitted via AJAX. When I click submit it gives me an Syntax Error:

```
SyntaxError: syntax error
[Break On This Error]   
   <!DOCTYPE html>
```

It references Line 31 which is this line of code:

```
var formResponse = eval(msg);
```

Here is the full AJAX Code:

```
function jqsub() {

var $f = $('#email-form');
var $m = $('#success-message');
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: $f.attr('action') + '&amp;JSON=1',
  data: $f.serialize(),
  success: function(msg) {
    var formResponse = eval(msg);
    if (formResponse.FormProcessV2Response.success) { 
            $f.fadeOut();
            $m.fadeIn().html('<p>Thank you for joining our mailing list.</p>'); 
    }

   },
   error: function(msg) {
   alert('error'+msg);
   return false;
   }
 });
}
```

What does this syntax error mean and how to I fix this?

Note: I am using a CMS called Business Catalyst and `FormProcessV2Response` is a part of their system.

Comment: It means `msg` isn't valid JavaScript. Why are you using `eval` anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your server's response contains HTML, not JSON. You eval JSON because JSON is a subset of JavaScript. You can't eval HTML, it's not valid JavaScript.

Comment: It turns out that Business Catalyst was returning HTML not JSON due to an error in one of their Modules. So you were correct. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

```
url: $f.attr('action') + '&amp;JSON=1'
```

should be

```
url: $f.attr('action') + '&JSON=1'
```

This will make it actually return JSON. You only use `&amp;` in HTML — you may have copied this from a link attribute or something.

Also, since you’re using jQuery, instead of using `eval`, you can use `$.parseJSON`. Or better, set `dataType: 'json'` in the `$.ajax` options and just use `msg` as-is! (And even if you weren’t, `JSON.parse` would still be preferable.)

Comment: How would I use `$.parseJSON`? JS is not my best area. Thanks for the help and advice!

Comment: @Lynda: `var formResponse = $.parseJSON(msg);` :)